# How can I add an event to react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using *react-color*. It provides two build in events: `onChange` and `onChangeComplete`.
While `onChange` fires in realtime when operating the color picker, `onChangeComplete` only fires when holding still for a short time.

However for my case, `onChangeComplete` does still fire too often because it seems to have a short timeout (like 500ms or something), not only when releasing the mouse button.

I need an event to really finalize a color picking and send it to all components that need to know it. This would be when the user releases the mouse button.

```
<SketchPicker
    onChange={(color) => { //fires all the time as it should
       handleChange(color);
    }}
    onChangeComplete={(color) => { //fires when stopping mouse movement for a short time
         handleChangeComplete(color); //Ok for setting local component state variables
    }}
    onMouseUp={(color) => { //not firing at all
         handleFinalChange(color); //supposed to run, when the user released mouse to promote it to React
    }}
/>
```

`onMouseUp` supposed to be an event React provides and it works in plain divs but for some reason not in components provided by this package. How do I add a custom event to the component here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either wrap the library component in a `div` and bind `onMouseUp` to it, or you'll need to modify the source code for that library.

Comment: I thought it would mess with the color picker's own event catchers but it seems to work.